# Automating/Improving workflow for adding HTML links to shapefile attribute tables in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, python, hyperlink

I'm doing some work that involves classifying aerial imagery. I'd like the consumers of this data to be able to access the photo associated with points through a hyperlink, to their location on a cloud storage service. I found good documentation on this process here:

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00s500000004000000

I've been able to add links one-by-one to shapefile attributes but there are many thousands of pictures in this dataset, and would take very long. I'm wondering if there might be some way to automate this process with a script of some sort, or perform a bulk job.
[image: Allowing hyperlinks from a field (PHOTO in this case)].

[image: The Layer's attribute table, the URL appears in the PHOTO field]

[image: Using the display tool allows selection of individual features, the URL can be accessed from here (blocked out in gray)]

Comment: Are your photos geotagged or are they just stored somewhere and you associate them with the points via field(s) or by name? If geotagged, there is a completely different workflow available.

Comment: If you have a table of feature IDs (or some unique attribute) and photo URLs, or some other way to easily relate a feature to a URL, then adding the URLs to an attribute is trivially easy in a Python arcpy script.  What do you currently have in terms of determining which feature should link to which URL?  What are the details for how you have been manually doing this?

Comment: The photos are geotagged. Currently, we use RoboGeo to generate a google earth KML. We ran into another issue when trying to manipulate KML attributes, which is why I tried exploring this option. To manually determine how features were related to links, I was using the image name to find the corresponding image on our cloud storage server, then copy/pasting the link into the layer's attribute table

Answer (score 2):

Without more detail it is difficult to know if this would work for your case. However one method of accomplishing this is as follows. If you give an example of your URL and data attributes we can provide more feedback on possible approaches.

Say your URL looks something like this:

```
https://docs.mycloud.com/aerials/img000675.png
```

If that last part of the URL (the photo file name) **img000675** corresponds to a unique ID field within your points data (i.e FID, imgID) you could use the field calculator to populate a "link" field with the appropriate URL.

[image: EX]

Notice how the URL is broken into pieces. The first part `https://docs.mycloud.com/aerials/img` and the file extension `.png` don't change so they are hard coded. The "[Mit_No]" is the unique field in my data that will correspond to the image name in the URL and will be different for each feature.

Note: If your image file names don't correspond to an attribute in your data then you will likely have to do some manual data entry.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The box links have a format like this: https://usu.box.com/s/jpd9xdyhodw91144mnpcsxfue3xmv0i5, they unfortunately don't have the uniform format as in your example

Comment: I see. Perhaps the [geo tagged approach](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/geotagged-photos-to-points.htm) would work. If you aren't forced to use the cloud box you could always explore other photo hosting options that would give you the desired url structure. I see you have the image name in the attribute table so if you used an ftp site for example the url would likely take the form of the above.